# stateparms are attached with current state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

when I pass the stateParams to another state, they concatenate with the state and getting following results in my IONIC App.

```
var $currState = $ionicHistory.currentView().stateId; 
$scope.consoleLog('$currState: ' + $currState); //$currState: app.stateA_purchaseData=[object Object]_supplierData=[object Object]"

$scope.consoleLog('$stateParams: ' + JSON.stringify($stateParams)); //$stateParams: {}
```

and here is the config

```
state('app.StateA', {
        url: '/test-url',
        templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        cache: false,
        params: {
            purchaseData: null,
            supplierData: null,
        }
    })


$state.go('app.StateA', {purchaseData: $scope.purchaseData, supplierData: $scope.supplierData });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because, in the documentation of `Ionic history` there is a method **`getCurrentStateId()` which concatenates the `statename` with `params`.**

**`Check from line no 142 in ionic_history.js in github documentation`**

```
function getCurrentStateId() {
    var id;
    if ($state && $state.current && $state.current.name) {
      id = $state.current.name;
      if ($state.params) {
        for (var key in $state.params) {
          if ($state.params.hasOwnProperty(key) && $state.params[key]) {
            id += "_" + key + "=" + $state.params[key];
          }
        }
      }
      return id;
    }
    // if something goes wrong make sure its got a unique stateId
    return ionic.Utils.nextUid();
  }
```

To get the parameters instead,
try,

`StateParams()` which calls `getCurrentStateParams()`

```
function getCurrentStateParams() {
    var rtn;
    if ($state && $state.params) {
      for (var key in $state.params) {
        if ($state.params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          rtn = rtn || {};
          rtn[key] = $state.params[key];
        }
      }
    }
    return rtn;
  }
```

**This actually return params object for you.**

[**Reference(source) of the above functions**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/1.x/js/angular/service/history.js#L1)

Comment: @Sarvan i am getting this error ""TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'StateParams'"